# ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'errors_file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/log/ErrorLoggers.log'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, apache, pycharm

I'm trying to deploy django project in AWS EC2. When I run my apache server error.log file  contains this. I don't know what I'm missing. Can't find file log/ErrorLogger.log.

```
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751531 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
122.176.187.97:54622] mod_wsgi (pid=18839): Target WSGI script 
'/home/ubuntu/django/pims/pims/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751588 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
122.176.187.97:54622] mod_wsgi (pid=18839): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 
'/home/ubuntu/django/pims/pims/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751761 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
122.176.187.97:54622] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751802 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
 122.176.187.97:54622]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 565, in configure
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751808 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
 122.176.187.97:54622]     handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751815 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
122.176.187.97:54622]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 738, in 
 configure_handler
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751819 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
122.176.187.97:54622]     result = factory(**kwargs)
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751826 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
122.176.187.97:54622]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 202, in __init__
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751830 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
122.176.187.97:54622]     BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, 'a', encoding, delay)
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751843 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
 122.176.187.97:54622]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 57, in __init__
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751848 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
 122.176.187.97:54622]     logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, 
 delay)
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751854 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
122.176.187.97:54622]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1032, in 
__init__
[Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751858 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
 122.176.187.97:54622]     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
 [Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751865 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
 122.176.187.97:54622]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1061, in _open
 [Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751869 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
 122.176.187.97:54622]     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
 [Wed Sep 02 08:50:20.751884 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 18839:tid 140404483544832] [remote 
 122.176.187.97:54622] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'/log/ErrorLoggers.log'
```

Comment: If there is not such file. You can try creating that file at that location. Maybe logs will be written in the file which you create. The filename should be same. Or there may be some permission problems with directory where logs are meant to be stored

Comment: File is there. But could be permission error. Please tell me how to give permissions.

Comment: Maybe this link could help you https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373

Comment: Now the file permissions looks like this. -rw-r--r--. This is also not solving the problem.

Comment: Did you create `log` directory in your project root directory after adding config of your loggers?